# "public" vs. "internal" C# class implementing IDispatch

Tags: idispatch, interopservices

I am writing a class that will serve as an IE WebBrowser container, and which is also going to be implementing the IDispatch interface, so some of its methods have DispID attributes:

```
public class IEContainer :
        IOleClientSite,
        IOleInPlaceSite
{

...
        [DispId(HTMLDispIDs.DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL)]
        public int Idispatch_AmbiantDlControl()
        {
            return (int)m_nFlags;
        }
...

}
```

This works fine and the method Idispatch_AmbiantDlControl gets called only when the class is "public". If I declare it "internal", the IDispatch calls are no longer received. Can someone explain why? Any way around it? I don't want this class to be publicly accessible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "public" for "private"